# Completely black screen on setting initial view controller in AppDelegate

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

All I want to do is go to the login screen if the user = nil. Otherwise it goes to the main/home section of the app which consists of the Tab Bar Controller's first view controller

Here is my app delegate:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil && !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasViewedWalkthrough") {

        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WalkthroughViewController") as? WalkthroughViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController


    } else if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil && UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasViewedWalkthrough") {

        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginViewController") as? LoginViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

    } else {

        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeTabBarController") as? MainTabBarViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

    }

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

I am not able to get to the onboarding or login screen. I am always led to the main screen. I know the screens are rendering fine if I manually set them as initial view controllers in storyboard.

I have tried numerous solutions and none of them are working.

**Update**
[image]

Comment: could you show us your project target page, click your project name in the project hierarchy and then click your project name once more under 'targets'

Comment: Is it under the General section (the horizontal menu at the top)? I dont see it there

Comment: yes that's it, just send a screenshot of that page]

Comment: Added it to the main original post.

Comment: what I'd recommend in doing instead is making a completely new storyboard and make it the initial view controller, add your app's logo or something on it and make it a Splashscreen sort of thing. Add that firebase logic in your AppDeleage file into that new viewcontroller and do a  `performseuge()` to either the loginViewController if they're not signed in or the home section of the app if they are. Then that way your user has some visual feedback of your app loading. If you need help with any of that, I can provide you with an answer to help you with that?

Comment: I see what you are saying. I am going to give that a shot. The only thing I do not understand is why I would need a separate storyboard for the login screen. I actually already have an onboarding/splash screen sort of a thing implemented.

Comment: BTW I am using Userdefaults for showing the onboarding screen.

Comment: check my answer if you'd like to do it like that

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeTabBarController") as? TabBarViewController // whatever your swift file is called 
        self.window?.rootViewController = storyBoard
```

use that code for each statement for the if statement, obviously change the names of the view controllers to the login one respectively.

Comment: In the last line it should be initialViewController instead of storyboard I presume. I tried this and it I am not getting a black screen anymore. But even in logged out state i.e. Auth = nil, I am ending up in the main section of the app instead of the login screen.

Comment: Okay so that answer there fixed your black screen issue? Update your question with your new, updated piece of code again for me...

Comment: @BVB09 I don't know whether this might be the problem or not, but I have a feeling it might be, you have used `initalViewController` for all three assignments of your view controllers, try changing them to their own name. For example, the first one to `let WalkthroughViewController` the next one to `let loginViewController` and the third to `let homeTabBarViewController` instead of having all three as `initalViewController`.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. I repeated the code that was originally outside the if blocks inside them and the result is the same.

Comment: At the top where it has `FirebaseApp.configure()` add `print(Auth.auth().currentuser` and tell me what it says

Comment: It crashed since I was not logged in and got this error and was unwrapping the value: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. If I were to repeat it but logged in this time then I get the FIRuser: 09576A6

Comment: Where was the error source in your code? What line?

Comment: Directly from the print statement you suggested since I have to force unwrap it.

Comment: The only reason to why it's always going to the main screen is that your `!UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasViewedWalkthrough")` have the wrong values, try removing them from the if statements and try the whole thing again to test if it's firebase or not.

Answer (score 0):

For people reading this in the future, iOS 13 introduced SceneDelegate and now all UI related stuff should be configured from that point.
I faced the same issue and solved it by using this code.
The custom window should be configured from here now.

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let sceneWindow = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    window = UIWindow(frame: sceneWindow.coordinateSpace.bounds)
    window?.windowScene = sceneWindow
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    if let navigationController = Storyboard.Main.initialViewController as? UINavigationController,
       let viewController = navigationController.children.first as? CountriesViewController {
        viewController.inject(CountriesViewModel(provider: CountryAPI(),
                                                 informTo: viewController),
                                                 navigator: CountriesNavigator(navigationController: navigationController))

        window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to create a new project from scratch, nothing worked.  It took some time but essentially I pasted all my files over and all my xibs over.  For the storyboards I always create a view that contains all other views.  When I copied that view and put the constraints of all zeros to the super view it all worked.  A lot of copying and pasting for no reason